# One/Two onion rings?

Tags: spoken-english, ambiguity, countable-nouns

When making an order, is it correct to say the following? If so, Why?  If not what is the correct way?

> Can I get one onion rings?

In case you want two servings,

> Can I get two onion rings?

Answer (score 3):

What you re trying to get is

> **an order of onion rings**
>
> Can I get a cheeseburger and **onion rings**?
>   *Can I get a cheeseburger and (an order of) onion rings?*

for more onion rings

> Can I get a cheeseburger and **two onion rings**?
>   *Can I get a cheeseburger and two (orders of) onion rings?*

The reason why it works is because onion rings come in *set amount orders* and everyone knows your not asking for only two onion rings.

Your order can be further shortened to

> **One cheeseburger, two onion rings**

and still be understood.

But say you are an onion freak and want extra onions on your burger, you might say:

> One cheeseburger with extra onions and two orders of onions rings.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I get one onion rings?

It depends on what you want to convey. If you *focus on the onion* then it should be okay since you want rings of one onion. But if you *focus on the rings*, then it is a mistake, as you understand, since rings are plural and cannot be together with the *cardinal number* one.

> Can I get two onion rings?

This sentence, unlike the previous one, means that you want two rings of of onion. It doesn't mean that you want two servings.